# C reading file using ./a.out<filename and how to stop reading

Tags: file

In my class today we were assigned a project that involves reading in a file using the ./a.out"<"filename command. The contents of the file look like this

```
16915  46.25  32  32
10492  34.05  56  52
10027  98.53  94  44
13926  32.94  19  65
15736  87.67  5  1
16429  31.00  58  25
15123  49.93  65  38
19802  37.89  10  20
-1
```

but larger

My issue is that any scanf used afterwards is completely ignored and just scans in what looks like garbage when printed out, rather than taking in user input. In my actual program this is causing an issue with a menu that requires input.

How do I get the program to stop reading the file provided by the ./a.out"<"filename command? 
also I stop searching at -1 rather than EOF for the sake of not having an extra set of array data starting with -1
ex

```
-1 0 0 0
```

in my real program the class size is a constant that is adjustable and is used to calculate class averages, I'd rather not have a set of 0's skewing that data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int i = 0,j = 1,d,euid[200],num;
        int tester = 0;
        float hw[200],ex1[200],ex2[200];
        while(j)
        {
                scanf("%d",&tester);
                if( tester == -1)
                {
                        j = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                        euid[i] = tester;
                }
                scanf("%f",hw+i);
                scanf("%f",ex1+i);
                scanf("%f",ex2+i);
                i++;
        }
        for(d = 0;d < 50;d++) /*50 because the actual file size contains much more than example*/
        {
                printf("euid = %d\n",euid[d]);
                printf("hw = %f\n",hw[d]);
                printf("ex1 = %f\n",ex1[d]);
                printf("ex2 = %f\n",ex2[d]);
        }
        printf("input something user\n");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        printf("This is what is being printed out -> %d\n",num);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem. Tried every method I could find to eat the remaining input in the buffer, but it never ends.

Got it to work using fopen and fscanf, but the prof. said he prefers the code using a.out < filename

Comment: Wonder what the chances of us being at the same school are? Anyways I emailed my professor, I don't think it's possible using that command. I'll let you know what he tells me when I get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is in fact not possible.